# Exporting a zope folder with python

Tags: python, zope

We have two zope servers running our company's internal site.  One is the live site and one is the dev site.  I'm working on writing a python script that moves everything from the dev server to the live server.  Right now the process involves a bunch of steps that are done in the zope management interface.  I need to make all that automatic so that running one script handles it all.  One thing I need to do is export one folder from the live server so that I can reimport it back into the live site after the update.  How can I do this from a python script?

We're using Zope 2.8 and python 2.3.4

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try to use the functions `manage_exportObject` and `manage_importObject` located in the file `$ZOPE_HOME/lib/python/OFS/ObjectManager.py`

Let say we install two Zope 2.8 instances located at:

- `/tmp/instance/dev` for the development server (port 8080)
- `/tmp/instance/prod` for the production server (port 9090)

In the ZMI of the development server, I have created two folders `/MyFolder1` and `/MyFolder2` containing some page templates. The following Python script exports each folder in .zexp files, and imports them in the ZMI of the production instance:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import urllib
import shutil

ids_to_transfer = ['MyFolder1', 'MyFolder2']

for id in ids_to_transfer:
    urllib.urlopen('http://admin:password_dev@localhost:8080/manage_exportObject?id=' + id)

    shutil.move('/tmp/instance/dev/var/' + id + '.zexp', '/tmp/instance/prod/import/' + id + '.zexp')

    urllib.urlopen('http://admin:password_prod@localhost:9090/manage_delObjects?ids=' + id)
    urllib.urlopen('http://admin:password_prod@localhost:9090/manage_importObject?file=' + id + '.zexp')
```

Answer (score 3):

To make this more general and allow copying folders not in the root directory I would do something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import urllib
import shutil

username_dev = 'admin'
username_prod = 'admin'
password_dev = 'password_dev'
password_prod = 'password_prod'
url_dev = 'localhost:8080'
url_prod = 'localhost:9090'

paths_and_ids_to_transfer = [('level1/level2/','MyFolder1'), ('level1/','MyFolder2')]

for path, id in ids_to_transfer:
    urllib.urlopen('http://%s:%s@%s/%smanage_exportObject?id=%s' % (username_dev, password_dev, url_dev, path, id))

    shutil.move('/tmp/instance/dev/var/' + id + '.zexp', '/tmp/instance/prod/import/' + id + '.zexp')

    urllib.urlopen('http://%s:%s@%s/%smanage_delObjects?ids=%s' % (username_prod, password_prod, url_prod, path, id))
    urllib.urlopen('http://%s:%s@%s/%smanage_importObject?file=%s.zexp' % (username_prod, password_prod, url_prod, path, id))
```

If I had the rep I would add this to the other answer but alas...
If someone wants to merge them, please go ahead.

Answer (score 1):

If you really move *everything* you could probably just move the Data.fs instead. But otherwise the import/export above is a good way.

Comment: I actually do move everything except one folder.  So, I export the one folder, move the data.fs, and then import the one folder back in.